# App relaunch state after pressing home button with videoview

Tags: android, video

I have a video player, when I start it and press launcher icon and again relaunch the app the video start playing from where it was.when I pause the video and press launcher icon and again relaunch the application.video is not in pause state. It again starts from last position.Thanks in advance

```
public class VideoFullscreenActivity extends Activity {


    private static boolean startFromZero = false;
    VideoView videoView;

    private  static  boolean isplaying = false;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    int restoredPosition;

    public static boolean isStartFromZero() {
        return startFromZero;
    }


    public static void setStartFromZero(boolean startFromZero) {
        VideoFullscreenActivity.startFromZero = startFromZero;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_fullscreen);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        editor = getSharedPreferences("VIDEO_POSITION", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("VIDEO_POSITION", MODE_PRIVATE);


        if (startFromZero) {
            editor.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0);//stopPosition is an int
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            setStartFromZero(false);
        }

        restoredPosition = prefs.getInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0);

        if (Utilities.checkInternetConnection(this)) {


            Intent intent = getIntent();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            // Set progressbar message
            pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            // Show progressbar
            pDialog.show();

            MediaController mediaController = new
                    MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

            if(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.URL)!= null)
            {
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.URL));
                videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

            } else if (intent.getStringExtra("VideoUrl") != null)
            {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put(APP_KEY, APPKEY_VALUE);
                headers.put(SESSION_ID, SharedInstance.getInstance().getLoginDetails().getSessionId());

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("VideoUrl"));
                Method setVideoURIMethod = null;
                try {
                    setVideoURIMethod = videoView.getClass().getMethod("setVideoURI", Uri.class, Map.class);
                    setVideoURIMethod.invoke(videoView, uri,headers);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //videoView.setVideoURI(uri,headers);
            }
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });

            if (prefs != null) {
                restoredPosition = prefs.getInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0); //0 is the default value.
            }
            videoView.seekTo(restoredPosition);
            videoView.start();
            Log.i("positionPlayback", "onCreate " + restoredPosition);

        } else {
            Utilities.showAlertLoginDialog(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.internet_unavailable_msg));
        }
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

//---------------------------------------------------------------//

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                this.onPrepared(mediaPlayer);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("positionPlayback", "onPause " + restoredPosition);
        if (videoView != null && videoView.isPlaying()) {
            videoView.pause();

        }
        restoredPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();

        editor.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", restoredPosition);//stopPosition is an int
        Utilities.hideKeybord(VideoFullscreenActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkForCrashes();
        startFromZero = false;
        if (Utilities.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            Log.i("positionPlayback", "onResume " + restoredPosition);
            pDialog.show();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    restoredPosition = prefs.getInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0);
                    videoView.seekTo(restoredPosition);
                    videoView.start();

                }
            });
        } else {
            Utilities.showAlertLoginDialog(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.internet_unavailable_msg));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void checkForCrashes() {
        CrashManager.register(this, BuildConfig.hockeyAppId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (prefs != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("VIDEO_POSITION", MODE_PRIVATE);
            restoredPosition = prefs.getInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0); //0 is the default value.
        }
        videoView.seekTo(restoredPosition);
        videoView.start();
        Log.i("positionPlayback", "onStart " + restoredPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("positionPlayback", "onStop 1 " + restoredPosition);
        if (videoView != null && videoView.isPlaying()) {
            videoView.pause();
        }
        editor.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", restoredPosition);//stopPosition is an int
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("positionPlayback", "onStop " + restoredPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        editor.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", restoredPosition);
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("positionPlayback", "onDestroy " + restoredPosition);
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("VIDEO_POSITION", MODE_PRIVATE);
        restoredPosition = prefs.getInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0);
        Log.i("positionPlayback", "onRestart " + restoredPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        editor.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0);
        editor.commit();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is ur question?

Comment: you can set a check in OnResume(). If the videoplayer is playing then set it to pause state.

Comment: my question is .. when i pause the video and press launcher .. and again relaunch the app video should be in pause state as previous. It happens with the playing state ..but not with the pause

Comment: @Vivek Mishra question seems bit unclear forget about launcher icon and say you open app what do you want to achieve?

Comment: you need to save your video position @onPause well  did you do that?

Comment: i want video to be in paused state if paused before home button and....i want playing state if video was in playing state before home button. @Charuක

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to make one status boolean to check video is manual pause or not.

```
boolean manual_pause = false;
```

in onPause check video status to affect on manual_pause.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("positionPlayback", "onPause " + restoredPosition);
    if (videoView != null && videoView.isPlaying()) {
        videoView.pause();
        manual_pause = false;
    } else if(videoView != null){
        manual_pause = true;
    }
    restoredPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();

    editor.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", restoredPosition);//stopPosition is an int
    Utilities.hideKeybord(VideoFullscreenActivity.this);

}
```

than check this status in onResume() to set video status previously.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkForCrashes();
    startFromZero = false;
    if (Utilities.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        Log.i("positionPlayback", "onResume " + restoredPosition);
        pDialog.show();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                restoredPosition = prefs.getInt("CURRENT_POSITION", 0);
                videoView.seekTo(restoredPosition);
                if(manual_pause) {
                    videoView.pause();
                    manual_pause = false;
                }else{
                    videoView.start();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        Utilities.showAlertLoginDialog(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.internet_unavailable_msg));
    }
}
```

You have to handle your previous status like this manualy.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: thanks @Mr.Sandy it works.. iwas putting the same solution but in wrong place ..actualy just  4 months of friendship with android :)

Comment: Okey, Nice to know that you get solution... If this answer help you than please give up vote and make it right. and All the best for your making long friendship with Android @Vivek Mishra

Comment: @VivekMishra I think you forgot to do. because I was not getting any status and effect in this answer from your side. so, please do it to make support and we get possitive response and happy to help all of required persons.

Comment: hello its showing thanks for feedback but reputatuion is just 11 so might be an issue

Comment: So, you will not able to make this answer as right (✔) with this reputation?

Comment: Okey.. Do it when eligible :) I think now you are eligible to do @VivekMishra... :)

Comment: yes i m ...please do one more help for me regarding gallery intent i have asked a question . thabnks in advance

Comment: Can you please accept this answer and make it (✔) to others are find solution like this issue easily from your question.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `editor.commit();` @ `onPause` you need to commit after you add a value!

Comment: should i put that after editor.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", restoredPosition);//stopPosition is an int

Comment: of course it **Commits your preferences changes back from this Editor to the SharedPreferences object it is editing** so once you done you should commit! check other scenarios as well i just checked on pause

Comment: i m sorry but that was not working. :( already spent a lot of time :(

Comment: @Vivek Mishra put a log `Log.d("MyCommitValue->",restoredPosition);` and see which value you commit as `restoredPosition` if it gets saved for sure when you open again it will work

Comment: how you can solve this is you need to check the values you save when you are committing and check the values that you get when starting then you can see where it has gone wrong, then you can apply a fix

Comment: yes.. after restarting AS it work.. idk why ... but thanks for help @Charu

Comment: @Vivek Mishra may be a chache issue but make sure to `commit();` after the changes :D

Comment: @Vivek Mishra but it cannot work just after you restart android studio has nothing to do with the logic and saving values after it builds the app! remove the commit again and see if it still works :) or not!